# Parameter expected warning

Tags: php

I have the following warning when I run my code:

call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'db_connect' not found or invalid function name

The code:

```
 require_once("mo_object.php");

 class MO_Model extends MO_Object
 {
    private $con; 

    static function db_query($qry)
    {
       $this->db_connect;

       return $qry;
    }

    function db_connect()
    {
       $con =  mysqli_connect($rconf['host'],$mo_conf['usr'],$mo_conf['password'],$mo_conf['da   tabase']);
    } 
}
```

Why I can't run db_connect function correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in a class by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. I became the db_connect function into static.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a class and these functions are both in the same class, try this:

```
static function db_query($qry)
{
   $this->db_connect();
   return $qry;
}

public function db_connect()
{
   $con = mysqli_connect($rconf['host'],$mo_conf['usr'],$mo_conf['password'],$mo_conf['database']);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the function is inside a class. I typed the following: $q = $this->db_connect(); return $qry; But then I have the error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context, that's why I used call_user_func.

Comment: Could you put up your full class for us?

Comment: I copied the whole class I have. But the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `call_user_func`? Call the function directly and return your connection in your `db_connect` function. When you build a database class you should open your connection when you create your object and work with that connection over the whole process.

Otherwise you have a lot of useless database connections. Perhaps its better if you use a persistent Layer like [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html) or the [Doctrine 2 ORM](http://Object%20Relational%20Mapper) or any other abstraction layer to get your data.

There are a lot of more layers to work with databases you can google them.